# How do I get the text value from a second <tr> tag with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to pass the date values that I get back from the datepicker plugin but the values are not showing up in the console.log() which means that they are not being sent. I am thinking that my problem is at

```
var $fel = $el.parent('tr:second').find('.datepicker');
var datepicker = $fel.text();
```

which gives me this error:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported
>   pseudo: second

my first `<tr>` tag has:

```
<tr class="main">  
    <td class="main_tr" data-id1="<?php $row["id"];?>" data-parentId="main"><?php $row["id"];?></td>
    <input type="hidden" name="name" id="name" class="name" value="<?php $row["name"];?>">
    <td><button id="find" data-id2="<?php $row["id"];?>">find</button></td>
</tr>
```

second `<tr>` tag

```
<tr>
    <td>Date Begin: <input type="text" class="datepicker" data-parentId="main" id="datepicker" name="datepicker">

    Date End: <input type="text" class="datepicker2" data-parentId="main" id="datepicker2" name="datepicker2"></td>

</tr>
```

this is my javascript:

```
    $(document).on('click', '#find', function(){
        //var id = $(this).data("id2");
        var $el = $(this);
        var id = $el.data("id2");

        var $fel = $el.parent('tr:second').find('.datepicker');
        var datepicker = $fel.text();

        var $fel2 = $el.parent('tr:second').find('.datepicker2');
        var datepicker2 = $fel2.text();


        $.ajax({
            url:"select_.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{
                id:id,
                datepicker:datepicker,
                datepicker2:datepicker2
            },
            dataType:"text",
            success:function(data){
                $('#live_view1').html(data);
                $('#live_view2').html(data);
                console.log(id);
                console.log(datepicker);
                console.log(datepicker2);
            }
        })
    });
```

Comment: use `:nth-child(2)` selector or `.eq(1)` method note that `.eq()` is index based that starts with 0 but `:nth-child()` starts with 1.  use `$el.parent('tr').next().find('.datepicker');`

Comment: That error message is pretty self-explanatory. If you're going to use jQuery, why not spend a few minutes familiarising yourself with the [list of selectors at the jQuery doco site](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `:eq(i)` pseudo, here you have to pass index started from ZERO.

```
var $fel = $el.parent().parent().('tr:eq(1) .datepicker');
var datepicker = $fel.text();
```

for more detail [check here](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

You have mutliple possitibilites:

**CSS**: First you can find all children witth the type of *tr* and there you can select the second on:

```
$('#parent_element_id').find('tr:nth-child(2)');
```

**JQuery:** Or you just grab all children as list, do not matter what type they are, and then just select the second one (counting from 0):

```
$('#parent_element_id').children().eq(1);
```